# Could genetic engineering enable humans to make use of titanium or some similar material instead of calcium for bone formation?

Tags: biochemistry, genetic-engineering, metals

I'm planing to create "super powers" born out of genetic engineering, but I don't want magic miracle stuff like an x-man, I'm looking for a realistic approach, so overall can you modify the materials biology uses to create us?

Edit: as suggested I'm adding abundance, bio availability and usefulness requirements to the mix of materials that could be used, feel free to add any material that is plausible.

Comment: I am sure by the time I researched the topic someone else will have posted an answer but I am curious so I will check. I am betting you could alter the methods with which the current materials are being used to create super humans but not sure about the materials themselves, probably, most likely.

Comment: We eat calcium. We don't eat titanium. Since we don't have onboard nuclear reactors, that means we and up with a shortage of titanium for our titanium bones.

Comment: Abundance, bioavailability and usefullness seem to be important here. @Eric could [edit] to include that requirement.

Comment: eed a certain amount of calcium stores in the body for muscles to work, so you need a different way to store calcium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, probably not.

Generally speaking, a hard tissue such as bone consists of a matrix of organic material, such as collagen in bones. Embedded in that matrix are bits of inorganic crystals such as silica, calcium carbonate, or hydroxyapatite (the inorganic component of bone). The body uses water to dissolve the crystalline materials into their component ions, then allows them to reform into crystals in the gaps in the matrix.

Many titanium oxides form similar crystals, and some are naturally occurring minerals (such as rutile, a form of titanium dioxide). However, they are generally insoluble in water, so they would be impossible for the body to break down and deposit inside an organic matrix.